# Gpars, name the threads

Tags: multithreading, grails

```
List<byte[]> outputBytes = []
GParsPool.withPool( ) {
            outputBytes = events.collectParallel{
                depositNoticeService.getDepositNotice( it.id )
            }
        }
```

I want to name each thread, so I can monitor it in logging, but I do not see any documentation on how to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to **get current thread**, and than you can change or get it options:

```
Thread.currentThread().getName()
Thread.currentThread().setName("NEW NAME")
```

I'm using Executors and here example that works for me:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*
import javax.annotation.*


def threadExecute = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
threadExecute.execute {
        log.info(Thread.currentThread().getName())
        log.info(Thread.currentThread().setName("NEW NAME"))
        log.info(Thread.currentThread().getName())
 }
 threadExecute.shutdown()
```